# How do I write data from python to Excel using xlwt without deletion of rows?

Tags: python, excel

```
from xlwt import Workbook  

counter=0
while True:
    func ()
    counter+=1


def func ():
    wb = Workbook()
    sheet1 = wb.add_sheet('Sheet 1')

    sheet1.write(counter, 0, longitude)
    sheet1.write(counter, 1, latitude)
    sheet1.write(counter, 2, number)

    wb.save('C:/Users/NAME/Desktop/Map/map.xlsx')
```

On the first call of this method, it properly transcribes the longitude, latitude, and number to the excel spreadsheet. However, when I call the method once again in the code with count incremented by 1, the original data disappears and the new data appears in the second row. I want a list of data with each row saved after each call of func (). No errors. [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UWtR.png)

Comment: Are you using the correct package? xlwt is for the older 2003 version of excel (*.xls). Use openpyxl for *.xlsx which also supports appending.

Comment: You're creating a new Workbook instance every iteration, so you're overwriting your previous data. As Mike67 correctly pointed out, you should be using openpyxl.